# How to create a data frame in R with named numerics and lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe

This might seem like a trivial question, but I am having problems with this.
I have a list of named numerics (I got them out of a nls by

```
error = coef(summary(m1))[, "Std. Error"][2]
errors[i] = list(error)
```

,
I hope it's not a problem that they are named since I don't know how to unname them) and a list of lists called depths I generate like this

```
depth= c(runif(n=1, min=0.01, max = 6), runif(n=7, min=0.01, max = 20))
depth<- sort(depth)
depths[i] = list(depth)
```

inside a for-loop over i.

Now I want to put them togehter into a data frame, because the i'th value in error belongs to the same entry in depth and I want to sort the data frame afterwards so I can sort it to see which depth creates more or less an error.

I tried
`comparison = data.frame(errors, depths)`
This doesn't give me two columns, one being  errors and one being depths.
Instead it creates a column for every error that repeats the value and column for every list in depths.
How can I create the data frame as I wish so I can relate the errors with the depth lists and sort them after the errors?

Edit:
`dput(head(errors))` results in the following:

```
list(c(D = 95.0366316885139), c(D = 4.39970337894091), c(D = 1.64857187195367), 
    c(D = 1.03736644269342), c(D = 2.78859988152878), c(D = 1.01132604633924))
```

`dput(head(depths))` results in:

```
list(c(2.8757584432466, 3.13134194160812, 5.00666030655848, 5.6528061668016, 
8.0060998139251, 9.94408561721444, 10.6993738641054, 15.2280608629016
), c(1.83155859559774, 2.02404017815599, 3.05270053320797, 3.399602308881, 
3.99466107267654, 6.86905775453197, 9.99144606708782, 12.6899819255993
), c(0.152889687146526, 2.26179468018236, 4.04482247331412, 6.49030452670995, 
7.20269280388486, 7.59870912223589, 11.7817946268013, 19.7157878024434
), c(0.035487746600993, 1.62364501114469, 2.3377970061847, 3.21925386766437, 
11.0224696304742, 13.4517430908256, 13.596371483712, 19.2027612853702
), c(1.06988511229167, 1.98849752927432, 6.25664629776496, 6.75547244368819, 
8.52860158402473, 8.91922583458247, 12.7884758723271, 17.5239637604193
), c(0.449312659096904, 1.99825130865211, 2.59652451965958, 5.30261293693446, 
5.44435022322228, 7.49861600056523, 11.1952574270428, 14.1488220158126
))
```

Comment: Please post `dput(head(error))`. Also what's `i` and why index `errors` and `depths` with it?

Comment: @Andre Wildberg I posted it in the edit. Both errors and depths are errors, that I created inside a for-loop like this

for (i in 1:10) { (...) tiefen[i] = list(tiefe) (...) errors[i] = list(error) (...)}

Comment: Based on the data given (`errors` = list with lengths of one per entry and `depths` = list with one vector) this might work for you: `data.frame(errors = unlist(errors), depths = depths[[1]])`

Comment: @Andre Wildberg Unfortunately this doesn't do the job. I also posted the same command with depths in the description. It is a list that contains lists, where each list contains 8 numerics. I need to match the errors with the depths like 
95.03 - c(2.87, 3.13, ...)
4.39 - c(1.83, 2.02, ...)
1.64 - c(0.15, 2.26, ...)
and so on.

Comment: Depending on your desired output you can either do `cbind(errors, depths)` with nested list elements, or `tibble::as_tibble(cbind(errors, depths)) %>% tidyr::unnest(errors) %>% tidyr::unnest(depths)` as valid tidy data frame, or even `names(depths) <- unlist(errors)`

Comment: The last one helped me a lot. I didn't think of just creating a named list and simply sorting by name. Thanks a lot Andre!

Comment: Use that with a grain of salt though, floats as names (even though cast to string) may create problems down the line and it also might create duplicated names.